# Is this a correct interpretation of Python code?

Tags: python

Here'a snippet of Python code:

```
 while i > 1:
    i = i - 1
    j = randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i-1
    items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
 return
```

I want to use this algorithm in my Pascal project. The first 3 lines are absolutely clear to me, but what does this program do in the fourth line of code? Does it assign the random value kept on the `j` to the `i`th slot in the array, and then moves to the left (keeping the "used" values on the right)?

Comment: If this is supposed to be Fisher-Yates shuffle, then it's wrong. It should be `j = randrange(i+1)` (so 0 <= j <= i).

Comment: It's Sattolo's algorithm, a variation of F-Y shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a neat syntax for swapping variables:

```
a,b = b,a
```

Now `a` has the value of `b` and vice-versa. The fourth line of your program does exactly this.